# Browse files dialog box using winforms and Managed C++

Tags: winforms, visual-c++, managed

I am working on Managed C++ for the first time... I have made a form using Winform which has a button to browse through directories for file and whichever path the user selects, the path should be visible on the text box.

I wanted to know how to create the file browser dialog box in Managed C++.

Attaching the image of the form if required.
[image]

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You're looking for [OpenFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.openfiledialog.aspx) or [SaveFileDialog](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.savefiledialog.aspx).

```
void button1_Click( Object^ /*sender*/, System::EventArgs^ /*e*/ )
       {
          Stream^ myStream;
          OpenFileDialog^ openFileDialog1 = gcnew OpenFileDialog;

          openFileDialog1->InitialDirectory = "c:\\";
          openFileDialog1->Filter = "txt files (*.txt)|*.txt|All files (*.*)|*.*";
          openFileDialog1->FilterIndex = 2;
          openFileDialog1->RestoreDirectory = true;

          if ( openFileDialog1->ShowDialog() == System::Windows::Forms::DialogResult::OK )
          {
             if ( (myStream = openFileDialog1->OpenFile()) != nullptr )
             {
                // Insert code to read the stream here.
                myStream->Close();
             }
          }
       }
```